# Almathswig error when trying to use almath to program NAO robot

Tags: python, importerror, robotics

Hi There Stackoverflow,

I am trying to program a NAO robot using Python. I would like to access some of the motion features of the NAO which require the "almath" module which I believe is installed as a part of the naoqi python sdk.

The naoqi python sdk is successfully installed on my machine and I have no problem importing "naoqi" into any of my scripts. However when trying to run any motion related scripts that require "almath" I run into the error seen in the second image. I am not sure why this module cannot be found when I have installed the naoqi library. The almathswig error is not well documented online so I thought I would put up a question to see if anyone can point my in the right track.

The error I am faced with is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Zachary Ringer/Desktop/Python/stackexchangeexample.py", line 4, in <module>
    import almath as m # python's wrapping of almath
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonNaoqi\lib\almath.py", line 28, in <module>
    from almathswig import *
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonNaoqi\lib\almathswig.py", line 26, in <module>
    _almathswig = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonNaoqi\lib\almathswig.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    import _almathswig
ImportError: No module named _almathswig
```

Within my naoqi library, the almath swig module is present
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdhFU.png

Please help, why can't python find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced the same while working with Almath. However, could you directly install the chorographe Version 2.8.6.X from *https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/nao6/downloads/nao6-downloads-windows*.

After installing it you can right click on the canvas and do select **Create New Box** then ***"python"***

In General Description write anything like Test then OK.

Double click on the Box and remove everything, then

import almath

After connecting the nodes run it,

Are you getting the same error.

If yes then you can 2.5 version.

There is some bug in the latest version. It is not working on my laptop as well. However Version 2.5 is working.

Comment: Hi there, it seems to work on the 2.5 version but I am trying to program my robot entirely within Microsoft Visual Studio Code and just utilize the simulation aspect of choregraphe. Do you know how I can use almath in VS? I have got it all working on linux but it would be great if I could do the same on Windows. The python interpereter from the latest sdk doesnt seem to work in VS and I couldnt find the interpereter for the Naoqi 2.5 sdk.

Comment: In fact, we had purchased the NAO Robot Version 6, and we have faced a lot of problem while working with python SDK. We had also contacted to NAO Robot Teams and they were also not having clue what's gone wrong. However, they did try to run it on their laptop and it was working. The difference was the lib folder located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Softbank Robotics\Choregraphe Suite 2.8\lib ... they had nearly 52 files but I got only 35.

My only hope is the 2.5 version chorographe and it too not well maintained for windows. You can program it within chorographe otherwise use Ubuntu 16.0

Answer (score 0):

I understand it's coming late, but this fixed the error for me.

Copy all the files with almath in their name from this file path C:\Users\owner\choregraphe-suite-2.8.7.4-win64-vs2015\lib
to  C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\almath where owner is the user who has installed choregraphe`.

This should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This could probably be the reason:
almath library >1.6.8 is missing some necessary files

please consider for linux:

> pip install almath==1.6.8

or for windows

> python -m pip install almath==1.6.8

and you should be good to go, this saved me from big trouble.
source: https://github.com/aldebaran/libalmath/issues/1#issuecomment-1069014699